# Macs to work on 802.1X wired network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, radius, osx-lion, 802.1, nps

We are in the process on 802.1X for all our wired clients. We are using NPS on Server 2008R2 as our Radius server. All our windows clients authenticate using just a computer certificate issued by our local CA.

The problem is that our CTO uses a mac so we need to be able to get his Mac and any other future macs to work on our network. Searching around various forums I can see that a lot of people have got it working for wireless networks using the PEAP protocol, but we want to use EAP-TLS. Has anyone got this working and if so how?

The mac is running OSX Lion with all updates. I tried exporting the computer certificate from a test computer and importing it to the mac, but this didnt work .